# Winform Webbrowser being recognized as a mobile device

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to open websites through the web browser control inside winforms. Although whatever websites it does open, it opens through the mobile version. My web browser is being recognizeed as a mobile device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can navigate to the page using [`Navigate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161355(v=vs.110).aspx) method and pass a suitable `User-Agent` string as `additionalHeaders` parameter.

The trick is useful for sites which detect mobile mode at server-side based on user-agent string. For some sites which doesn't detect mobile mode and only have client-side responsive design which is based on browser size, you can resize the browser control to a suitable size to show mobile view.

**Example**

Here is an [example](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent) of user agent string of Edge on Windows Phone 10.
You may want to use [different user agent](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/).

```
var additionalHeaders = "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 6.0.1; " +
    "Microsoft; Lumia 950 XL Dual SIM) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) " +
    "Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063\r\n";

this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com", null, null, additionalHeaders);
```

As result you see stackoverflow site in mobile mode:

[image]

**Note - As a better option, Set the user agent for all subsequent requests**

As an option, to set the user agent for all the subsequent requests you can use the following code:

```
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(int dwOption, string pBuffer,
    int dwBufferLength, int dwReserved);
const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT = 0x10000001;

string additionalHeaders = "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 6.0.1; " +
    "Microsoft; Lumia 950 XL Dual SIM) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) " +
    "Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063\r\n";
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, 
        additionalHeaders, additionalHeaders.Length, 0);
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");
}
```

Comment: Will this allow me to view websites in the non-mobile version?

Comment: You can set null as the `additionalHeaders` parameter to view non-mobile version.

Comment: I removed the part of answer which focused on script error. If you need that part you can see it in revisions. It seems the post answers your question. Let me know if you have any question about the answer or if you find the answer helpful :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you very much for this simple solution, however if the user clicks on links, or google something that will direct to normal web pages, how to set that behaviour to mobile mode as well?

Comment: @Rafa No problem. Hmm, may be you can try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34496568/3110834). Let me know the result ...

Comment: @RezaAghaei I'm trying to reproduce that in C++/CLI but I'm getting some issues, take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361094/add-a-customized-header-to-webbrowser-control-for-all-requests-in-c-cli

Comment: @Rafa I also updated this post with another solution.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you very much, your solution posted in my question worked fine, but this one is way shorter and simpler, is there a difference, I mean should I use this one instead?

Comment: @Rafa I prefer solution of this post.