# Use a specific viewport width in a WebBrowser component

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do I limit the width of a webpage inside a WebBrowser component so that the content is displayed in a "mobile" format, no horizontal scrolling is required and the font is still readable?

I have a relatively small WebBrowser component that needs to display mainly text websites alongside the rest of the form's controls. I'd have to make it really wide so that the font is readable and the whole text line fits inside the control. If I could somehow limit the viewport, like it happens in most browsers when you simply zoom in (no horizontal scrolling needed, the site resizes itself, provided it is responsive to narrower screen resolutions). Changing the zoom in the WebBrowser control introduces scrollbars and doesn't change the way the entire page is rendered.

Comment: [Winform Webbrowser being recognized as a mobile device](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35905628/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei This is an interesting way to handle some cases, but as more and more websites rely on responsiveness based on style sheets, I need a client-based solution. Unless I'm mistaken, in case of many modern websites, changing the client agent string won't really change the content sent back to the client. I'm not a web developer, but that seems like the "old" way of doing things. Besides that, I think the solution I'm looking for would change the rendering engine's settings and ultimately somewhat work even for websites that don't implement any kind of responsiveness.

Comment: It depends to the site which you want to show. Some sites return different contents for mobile browsers, some others rely on media queries and client-side responsiveness. If the site is yours, you can use either of these options based on your skill/requirements. If the site is not yours, it would be hard (but probably possible) to apply new styles to the site.

Comment: If the site was mine, or if it was a single site, I would come up with a better way of presenting the information. The thing is I have to support a few different sites and make sure other sites also display as well as it's possible.

Comment: This would probably need to be configured for each site visited, but you could modify the attributes on the browser's `Document.Body` to reduce the rendered font size.