# Detect if website runs using webview in windows forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, winforms, webview

As above. I don't need to do anything fancy with it. I've done a bit of a research around, but I can't seem to find proper solution. I am planning on hiding side bar in my React app if user is running website via Webview in Windows forms app. What would be the best way of approaching it? 
Checking for version or what browser is running on, is a no go, since Webview is using either default browser or browser that is described in method, so it would just return that.
Bear in mind that detection could be done in either Forms app or React app, it doesnt matter which.
 Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you the author of that Windows Forms application?

Comment: If you are owner of the application, you can send a [different user agent string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35905628/3110834).

Comment: Yes I am. This sounds like a good solution. Can you write this as an answer I will tick it for you so you can get some points :) Thank you

Comment: No problem, I'll post an answer, suggesting a few option, including the one that I mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also can think of the following solutions:

- **Handle it by DOM manipulation in the applicatoin:** As an option your application can hide the side bar by finding the element in DOM and hide it.
- **Send a new user agent string to Server and render different output by server:** As another option, you can think of your application as a new user agent. So you can send a custom user agent header along with your request. This is the way that I've already used to pretend the [request is coming from a mobile phone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35905628/3110834). You can do something similar for your application.

**Example**

```
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(int dwOption, string pBuffer,
    int dwBufferLength, int dwReserved);
const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT = 0x10000001;

string additionalHeaders = "User-Agent:MyApp\r\n";
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT,
        additionalHeaders, additionalHeaders.Length, 0);
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");
}
```

Then your site can decide about rendering base on the user agent.