# login automatically to NTLM Authentication site in Webbrowser WPF_C#

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, ntlm, ntlm-authentication

I try to open a site but first must fill username and password. I have username and password and I want to fill username and password in my code and users not see Authentication.
this is a sample, when click on button load page in WebBrowser tag:

[image]

my code:

```
string url = "http://sample.com";
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string userName = "username";
    string password = "pass"; 
    byte[] authData = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userName+":"+password);
    string authHeader = "WWW-Authentication: NTLM " + Convert.ToBase64String(authData) + "\r\n";
    myweb.Navigate(url,"", null, authHeader);

}
```

I read a lot solution but not work or I can't understand.

Comment: You are sending a request from a client to a server and the username and password has to be a parameter in the request.  Parameters are added to a request either by putting the parameter in the URL after a question mark or by adding a http header to the request.  The second method is preferred when using HTTPS (secure) because the parameter gets encrypted.

Comment: sorry. can you give me a sample about using header for pass parameter that support NTLM?

Comment: Looks like the header is automatically being added in the Navigate message.  it depends on the protocols that are implemented on your network if NTLM will work.  NTLM is a protocol.   Basic is not NTLM.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/understanding-http-authentication?force_isolation=true#:~:text=NT%20LAN%20Manager%20(NTLM)%20authentication,between%20the%20client%20and%20server.

Comment: I read this page but. I try NTLM instead of Basic but not pass NTLM again. if you can, please lead me another way.

Comment: Try HTTPS instead of HTTP : string url = "https://sample.com";  The last parameter in the Navigate is a header which has the format <Header Name : Text> which has a name, colon, and value.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496568/add-a-customized-header-to-webbrowser-control-for-all-requests-in-c?force_isolation=true

Comment: sorry I can't use https, because sample.com is not mine. just I use site`s services.

Comment: If the server requires HTTPS than you have to use HTTPS. HTTPS uses a certificate and you may already have the certificate install on your machine to work with HTTPS.  There ae generic certificates that allow all uses access to a server.  HTTPS just means the message are encrypted so hackers cannot see the actual data.  It doesn't necessarily mean that the server is restricting access to the server.  In some case a site may use special certificates that block access.